# Autoincriment в базе данных

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Суть проблемы: у меня есть база данных в ней хранятся различные таблицы, так вот в некоторых таблицах есть айди, который обозначен как BIGSERIAL тоесть он автоинкрементится после добавления каждой новой записи в таблицу, мне надо сделать так, чтобы после junit тестов автоинкремент(счетчик) сбрасывался, подскажите как это сделать.

Comment: при создании таблиц с полем bigserial postgresql на самом деле делает поле bigint и создает секвенс из которого беруться значения. Посмотрите имя этого секвенса, обычно оно имя-таблицы_имя-колонки-id. А дальше `alter sequence имя restart`

Comment: Не стоит проводить unit тесты на боевой БД. А если это тестовая БД, то какая разница с какими id там создаются записи? От этого все равно ничего не зависит. Чем вам это мешает?

Comment: у меня в основной бд есть тестовая схема - копия рабочей

Comment: Mike оформи как ответ, спасибо большое и такой вопрос, как это можно делать автоматически после каждого теста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании таблиц с полем bigserial postgresql на самом деле делает поле bigint и создает секвенс из которого беруться значения. Посмотрите имя этого секвенса, обычно оно имя-таблицы_имя-колонки-id. А дальше alter sequence имя restart